# Update Fragment in ViewPager From getItemPosition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-tablayout

I have a screen which has the new TabLayout from the design support library. I also have a ViewPager which is used to display a Fragment. This Fragment displays different lists of views depending on which tab is selected.

The app receives a response to a network call, my activity updates the FragmentPagerAdapter belonging to the ViewPager with the data returned by the response, in my case this is 3 lists.

In my ViewPager I override the `onPageChangeListener()` to detect when a page has been selected, and then I make a call to my FragmentPagerAdapter with the new tab position. I also call `notifyDataSet()` in order to redraw the view.

I override the `getItemPosition()` method to determine which list should be passed to the Fragment. However I don't think that this is the correct way to do it as their is a good deal of overdraw occurring from the `getItemPosition`. The method is actually updating each of the fragments with the same list of results. When scrolling to the next tab the current list is visible in the next tab until the scroll is release, then the fragment redraws with the correct list.

My question is am I taking the correct approach to displaying the lists in my ViewPager Fragments? Or am I seriously overcomplicating things? I don't have much experience with ViewPagers or FragmentPagerAdapters so any input would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as below.

Adding a fragment (called from `onResume()`)

```
private void addFragment() {

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    mMyPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            SampleActivity.this);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(final int i, final float v, final int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int i) {
            mMyPagerAdapter.updateTabPosition(i);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int i) {
        }
    });

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_tab_layout);
    mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    if (shouldMakeNetworkCall()) {
        getLists();
    }
}
```

The ViewPager FragmentPagerAdapter class

```
public class MyFragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
private List<MyListType> mListOne;
private List<MyListType> mListTwo;
private List<MyListType> mListThree;
private int mTabPosition;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return MyFragment.newInstance(mListOne);
        case 1:
            return MyFragment.newInstance(mListTwo);
        case 2:
            return MyFragment.newInstance(mListThree);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof MyFragment) {

        switch (mTabPosition) {
            case 0:
                ((MyFragment) object).setupUI(mListOne);
                break;
            case 1:
                ((MyFragment) object).setupUI(mListTwo);
                break;
            case 2:
                ((MyFragment) object).setupUI(mListThree);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}


public void updateTabPosition(int tabPosition) {
    mTabPosition = tabPosition;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I do think you're complicating this.

For me the best solution is to have 3 network calls, each for the fragment in the `ViewPager`. Let the fragments manage their calls on their own as you would do on a single fragment `Activity`. This way you'll even be able to show and hide progress on each fragment if you want the proper UX. I recommend using [Switcher](https://github.com/jkwiecien/Switcher) for that

The question is can you make separate calls? Bacause if you can't it would be making the same big call 3 times which is not the smartest idea. In this second case you could start every fragment with progress spinning and let the activity make the call. For me the prefferable solution to communicate with `ViewPager` fragments would be using [events](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). You just make the call in the activity and after it's loaded you split the data respectively and send 3 events with the data inside it and let ach fragment response to them. Just register to EventBus inside `onAttach` and unregister in `onDetach` methods